# Receive 403 Forbidden from Keycloak on localhost:3000?

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am building a web app based on ReactJS and it is running during the bulding process on the `http://localhost:3000`. For security reason, all backend and web apps are protected through Keycloak.
At the moment, Keycloak and backend service account are running on the Kubernetes cluster as you can see on the picture below:

[image]

The web app is also procected through Keycloak and it is running on `http://localhost:3000`. So, when I start the web app, it redirects me to the login page of the Keycloak. After the successfull login, it redirects back to the web app. Afterwards, the web app makes a request to the backend service `https://account.dev.example.io` and I receive the return http code **403**.

Do I receive the return code `403` because of `http` protocol instead of `https`?
Or what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Here is the overview of the request and response:
[image]

I forgot to mention that I have one more web app running on the kubernetes and it also makes a request to backend service account. This works like a charm.

Comment: I'm using the same flow and having the same issue. Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 means Forbidden / No access. It could be that your react client is not utilizing the `access_token` it gets from keycloak.

You should check out Google's AppAuth-JS project, it can help with the auth flow not only in browsers but native applications

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I put in the request header the bearer access token.  It should work.

Comment: I don't think http vs https is the problem here, have you examined the logs in your server application to ensure keycloak is configured properly there?